# Joomla Shortcode Ultimate plugin duplicating link ID's when creating button

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions

Over the past few months we have been developing a new Joomla site (3.4.3). The first initial install was on a linux host, using the [Effortless template](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwiL1_ilqqHIAhWTtoAKHaOCA6M&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthemeforest.net%2Fitem%2Feffortless-multipurpose-joomla-template%2F7645155&usg=AFQjCNFS_v1XbYdkHxOgrOlcJbwwZLlcBQ&sig2=QFiLfykEOWqShr8eVHIAIg&bvm=bv.104226188,d.dmo) and everything was going fine. Now that we're done working with the other developer, we're moving the site back to our host (Windows-based). We used Akeeba backup and have everything transferred over, but now we're experiencing issues with our shortcode buttons.

Nothing was changed in the process of the migration, but now the original buttons that were created on the first version (two sets of buttons per item, one grey/blue hover, one blue/grey hover) are all out of whack. At times, on page refreshes, the buttons would randomly change color. The temporary visual fix was to just CSS hack them to be all grey while we wait for the developer (on vacation).

We've noticed that when we create the buttons via the shortcode generator modal box, and inspect the source, they have the same a id=.

This is how the shortcode generates via the plugin (all well and good)

1. [button url="http://www.yahoo.com" color="#ffffff" background="#195eaa" radius="0px" icon="icon: info-circle" icon_color="#195eaa"]Yahoo[/button]
2. [button url="http://www.google.com" color="#195eaa" background="#efefef" background_hover="#195eaa" radius="0px" icon="icon: info-circle" icon_color="#195eaa"]Google[/button]

Which you can see creates the different color versions, yet inspecting the source reveals both buttons have the same a id

- a id="subtn_560d2d5a40678"

I'm assuming this is the major cause of the problem. It was suggested that we downgrade our php version to 5.4 (we WERE on 5.6), but tried 5.4.x and 5.5.x as well and that didn't make any progress.

Does anyone have any possible insight? We have support tickets in with the developer, but who knows if/when we will get a fix to this. We are fairly new to Joomla (at least as far as troubleshooting is concerned) and don't know what else we could possibly try as a fix.

Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Joomla Shortcode Ultimate is a commercial plugin, and includes 6 months of support. The plugin developer might be able to provide better answers.

Comment: Thanks, I've already contacted them...but they have been on vacation for a while now. It's a shot in the dark that someone might have had a similar experience.